# How to archive mail in Outlook 2016 with a shortcut?

Tags: applescript, ms-office, automator, automation

Outlook 2016 has removed support for AppleScript. I used to use a script to move my mail to the Archive folder on Ctrl-A. How do I restore that functionality?

Answer (score 4):

One could also do the following:

- In the **Outlook** Menu *Messages*, look for the *Move >* option.  See if there is a *Archive (provider)* menu option.

Much like this:

[image]

That being the case, mapping a key to it can be done in the  **Keyboard** preferences.

- Go to **System Preferences**
- Select **Keyboard**
- Select the *Shortcuts* tab
- Click the Plus sign button and create an **Application Specific** shortcut.  (Preventing system wide use)
- Type in the *Menu* option from Outlook *exactly* as it appears in the menu.
- Type your preferred shortcut

Now, go back to **Outlook** and test it.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This reply contained detailed instructions and a script. Both have been moved to https://github.com/proski/MacOutlookArchive and greatly reworked.